# Python interpreter as shared library

Tags: python, embed, shared-libraries

i wanted to embed python into my application. how can i compile python from source as shared library (.dll or .so)? the default configuration only produces python executable.

Comment: `the default configuration only produces python executable` That's not true

Comment: You just [didn't read the docs](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html)

Answer (score 2):

> the default configuration only produces python executable.

Incorrect. The "executable" is a very thin wrapper around the shared library that sets up the interpreter object and runs it. They are there; look harder.